# Can't convert FloatBuffer to float[] (UnsupportedOperationException)

Tags: java, arrays, buffer

I'm actually coding a cube mesh where in the super method I need to pass cube vertices, which is a float[], but I want to do it in a "human friendly way" so I've done this :

```java
private static FloatBuffer vertices = MemoryUtil.memAllocFloat(72);
private static final float[] A={0,0,0},B={0,1,0},C={1,1,0},D={1,0,0},E={0,0,0},F={0,1,0},G={1,1,0},H={1,0,0}; //Vertices

public class MyClass extends MyMeshClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
       super(
                vertices
                //Front
                .put(A).put(B).put(C).put(D)
                //Back
                .put(E).put(F).put(G).put(H)
                //Right
                .put(D).put(C).put(G).put(H)
                //Left
                .put(A).put(B).put(F).put(E)
                //Top
                .put(B).put(F).put(G).put(C)
                //Bottom
                .put(A).put(E).put(H).put(D).array(),
                Doing other cool stuff here);
    }
}
```

But I end up with a UnsupportedOperationException when converting to array, So I've tried differently by transforming FloatBuffer into array like this

```java
public static float[] toArray(FloatBuffer buffer)
    {
        float[] array = new float[buffer.limit()];
        buffer.get(array);
        return array;
    }
```

But I get a BufferUnderflowException on the get(array).

Does anyone know why it is not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to javadoc for `Buffer.array()` `UnsupportedOperationException` will be thrown if buffer is not backed by accessible array - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#array--

Such situation will happen i.e. when buffer utilizes array allocated not in JVM heap, but in native memory. Since LWJGL's `MemoryUtil.memAllocFloat` is optimized for opengl I guess it utilizes native memory, hence `array()` method invoked on such buffer fails.

If you want allocate buffer in heap you can just use i.e.

```
        FloatBuffer vertices = FloatBuffer.allocate(72);
```

or

```
        FloatBuffer vertices = FloatBuffer.wrap(new float[72]);
``
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Effectively I missed that memAllocFloat is from LWJGL, your solution is great

Answer (score 0):

Did you do try it like this?

```
FloatBuffer buf = FloatBuffer.allocate(10);
buf.put(1f).put(2f).put(3f).put(new float[]{4,5,6});
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buf.array()));
```

Prints

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```